# Primefaces 3.5 Dashboard Component

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, primefaces

I want to implement the pf 3.5 [dashboard component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dashboard.jsf) I am using this in my `*.xhtml` Page:

```
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

                <p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardBean.model}">
                    <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{dashboardBean.handleReorder}"
                        update="growl" />

                    <p:panel id="products" header="Products">
                        <h:outputText value="Product Content" />
                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panel id="plans" header="Plans">
                        <h:outputText value="Plans Content" />
                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panel id="notes" header="Notes">
                        <h:outputText value="Notes Content" />
                    </p:panel>
                </p:dashboard>
```

and as my backend:

I am using the same bean as from the [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dashboard.jsf) above and:

```
public DashboardBean() {  
    model = new DefaultDashboardModel();  
    DashboardColumn column1 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();  
    DashboardColumn column2 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();  
    DashboardColumn column3 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();  

    column1.addWidget("products");  

    column2.addWidget("plans");  

    column3.addWidget("notes");  

    model.addColumn(column1);  
    model.addColumn(column2);  
    model.addColumn(column3);  
}
```

However, when I open my page on my server nothing gets shown up. My html output:

```
<form id="form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/ProductOverview.xhtml" method="post" name="form">
<input type="hidden" value="form" name="form">
<span id="form:growl"></span>
<div id="form:board" class="ui-dashboard"></div>
<input id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="-5329509311621774370:-4596343252720161135" name="javax.faces.ViewState">
</form>
```

I really appreciate your reply!

Comment: how about adding `@ManagedBean` and `@SessionScoped` annotations ? Like this public `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped public DashboardBean()`

Comment: Daniel pls write it as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Adding ManagedBean and SessionScoped works for you? I am having the same problem but added those 2 annotations to my backing bean do not work. the page does not render anything. Do you add any css or js in header? I am using Primefaces 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a  `@ManagedBean` and `@SessionScoped`  (for example) annotations,

Like this

```
@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped 
public DashboardBean(){
```

Answer (score -1):

Your xhtml page probably has an error. You are reffering to `#{dashboardBean.handleReorder}` which I can not see in your code(unless you didnt post it), if there is no method handleReorder in your bean then it will not correctly build your page.

So remove the listener method or create it method.